# When I am inserting data in firebase, the data is submitted unlimited time till the run is stopped-android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Iam beginner with the firebase, and iam trying to insert data into the firebase, I faced a problem, that when I pressed insert button, the same data is submitted many times and it doesnt stop inserting until the run is stopped
I am using push() function but i dont know where the problem is in my code
can any one help me? 
[my firebase looks like this when i submitted one data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUu9S.png)
here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fill_request_page);
    Title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Title);
    Content = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Content);
    insert =(Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);

    edittxtDate =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxtDate);
    edittxtTime =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxtTime);
    edittxtExpDate=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxtExpDate);

    location = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.location);
    typeof=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.typeof);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref1 = database.getReference("requests");



    imagebtnTime.setOnClickListener(this);
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageReference = storage.getReference();


private void getValues(){
    request1.setTitle(Title.getText().toString());
    request1.setContent(Content.getText().toString());
    request1.setDate(edittxtDate.getText().toString());
    request1.setTime(edittxtTime.getText().toString());
    request1.setLocation(location.getSelectedItem().toString());
    request1.setExpDate(edittxtExpDate.getText().toString());
    request1.setTypeof(typeof.getSelectedItem().toString());
}
public void btnInsert1(View view){

    ref1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DatabaseReference ref2=ref1.push();
            String id=ref2.getKey();

            request1 =new requests();
            getValues();

            ref1.child(id).setValue(request1);

            Toast.makeText(FillRequestPage.this,"Data inserted....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

please help me

Comment: Im gonna say the problem is that you have the insert inside the onDataChanged, and every time the insert takes place, the data changes and is restarted infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending data to the database, you do not need to use `AddValueEventListener(..)`, you can just do this:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
ref1 = database.getReference("requests");
DatabaseReference ref2=ref1.push();
String id=ref2.getKey();
request1 =new requests();
ref1.child(id).setValue(request1);
//some code may be missing
```

`AddValueEventListener(..)` is used to retrieve data from the database.

Comment: that is great, so happy for you!! Happy coding!!